# Wordcount on (Key,Value) outputs from a Map Reduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, word-count

I have several  `(title , text )` ordered pairs obtained as an output from a MapReduce application in Hadoop using Java.

Now I would like to implement Word Count on the text field of these ordered pairs.

So my final output should look like :

```
(title-a , word-a-1 , count-a-1 , word-a-2 , count-a-2 ....)

(title-b , word-b-1, count-b-1 , word-b-2 , count-b-2 ....)
.
.
.
.
(title-x , word-x-1, count-x-1 , word-x-2 , count-x-2 ....)
```

To summarize , I want to implement wordcount separately on the output records from first mapreduce. Can someone suggest me a good way to do it or how I can chain a second map reduce job to create the above output or format it better ?

The following is the code , borrowed it from github and made some changes

```
package com.org;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamConstants;//XMLInputFactory;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.DataOutputBuffer;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptID;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;               
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import javax.xml.stream.*;

public class XmlParser11
{

    public static class XmlInputFormat1 extends TextInputFormat {

    public static final String START_TAG_KEY = "xmlinput.start";
    public static final String END_TAG_KEY = "xmlinput.end";


    public RecordReader<LongWritable, Text> createRecordReader(
            InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext context) {
        return new XmlRecordReader();
    }

    /**
     * XMLRecordReader class to read through a given xml document to output
     * xml blocks as records as specified by the start tag and end tag
     *
     */
    // @Override
    public static class XmlRecordReader extends
            RecordReader<LongWritable, Text> {
        private byte[] startTag;
        private byte[] endTag;
        private long start;
        private long end;
        private FSDataInputStream fsin;
        private DataOutputBuffer buffer = new DataOutputBuffer();

        private LongWritable key = new LongWritable();
        private Text value = new Text();
        @Override
        public void initialize(InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
            startTag = conf.get(START_TAG_KEY).getBytes("utf-8");
            endTag = conf.get(END_TAG_KEY).getBytes("utf-8");
            FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit) split;

            // open the file and seek to the start of the split
            start = fileSplit.getStart();
            end = start + fileSplit.getLength();
            Path file = fileSplit.getPath();
            FileSystem fs = file.getFileSystem(conf);
            fsin = fs.open(fileSplit.getPath());
            fsin.seek(start);

        }
    @Override
    public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException,
                InterruptedException {
            if (fsin.getPos() < end) {
                if (readUntilMatch(startTag, false)) {
                    try {
                        buffer.write(startTag);
                        if (readUntilMatch(endTag, true)) {
                            key.set(fsin.getPos());
                            value.set(buffer.getData(), 0,
                                    buffer.getLength());
                            return true;
                        }
                    } finally {
                        buffer.reset();
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    @Override
    public LongWritable getCurrentKey() throws IOException,
                InterruptedException {
            return key;
        }

    @Override
    public Text getCurrentValue() throws IOException,
                InterruptedException {
            return value;
        }
    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
            fsin.close();
        }
    @Override
        public float getProgress() throws IOException {
            return (fsin.getPos() - start) / (float) (end - start);
        }

        private boolean readUntilMatch(byte[] match, boolean withinBlock)
                throws IOException {
            int i = 0;
            while (true) {
                int b = fsin.read();
                // end of file:
                if (b == -1)
                    return false;
                // save to buffer:
                if (withinBlock)
                    buffer.write(b);
                // check if we're matching:
        if (b == match[i]) {
                    i++;
                    if (i >= match.length)
                        return true;
                } else
                    i = 0;
                // see if we've passed the stop point:
                if (!withinBlock && i == 0 && fsin.getPos() >= end)
                    return false;
            }
        }
    }
}


    public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text,Text, Text> {
  @Override
  protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
                 Mapper.Context context)
  throws
  IOException, InterruptedException {
    String document = value.toString();
    System.out.println("'" + document + "'");
        try {
      XMLStreamReader reader =                      XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(new     
           ByteArrayInputStream(document.getBytes()));
  String propertyName = "";
  String propertyValue = "";
  String currentElement = "";
  while (reader.hasNext()) {
    int code = reader.next();
    switch (code) {
      case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT: //START_ELEMENT:
        currentElement = reader.getLocalName();
        break;
      case XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS:  //CHARACTERS:
        if (currentElement.equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
          propertyName += reader.getText();
          //System.out.println(propertyName);
        } else if (currentElement.equalsIgnoreCase("text")) {
     propertyValue += reader.getText();
          //System.out.println(propertyValue);
        }
        break;
    }
  }
  reader.close();
  context.write(new Text(propertyName.trim()), new Text(propertyValue.trim()));

}
    catch(Exception e){
            throw new IOException(e);

            }

  }
}
public static class Reduce
extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

  @Override
  protected void setup(
  Context context)
  throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    context.write(new Text("<Start>"), null);
  }

  @Override
  protected void cleanup(
  Context context)
  throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    context.write(new Text("</Start>"), null);
  }

  private Text outputKey = new Text();
  public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values,
                 Context context)
  throws IOException, InterruptedException {
for (Text value : values) {
      outputKey.set(constructPropertyXml(key, value));
      context.write(outputKey, null);
    }
 }

  public static String constructPropertyXml(Text name, Text value) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("<property><name>").append(name)
    .append("</name><value>").append(value)
    .append("</value></property>");
    return sb.toString();
  }
}



    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
            Configuration conf = new Configuration();

            conf.set("xmlinput.start", "<page>");
            conf.set("xmlinput.end", "</page>");
            Job job = new Job(conf);
            job.setJarByClass(XmlParser11.class);
            job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

            job.setMapperClass(XmlParser11.Map.class);
            job.setReducerClass(XmlParser11.Reduce.class);

            job.setInputFormatClass(XmlInputFormat1.class);
            job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

            FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

            job.waitForCompletion(true);
    }
}
```

The wordcount code we find online does the word count of all files and gives the output . I want to do the wordcount for each of text fields separately. The above mapper is used to pull title and text from an XML document . Is there any way I can do the wordcount in the same mapper. If I do that , my next doubt is how do I pass it along with the already existing key value pairs (title,text) to the reducer. Sorry , I am not able to phrase my question properly but I guess the reader must have got some idea

Comment: a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) would make this question a lot easier to read and understand

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I have understood it properly. So I have many questions along with my answer.

First of all whoever has written this code is probably trying to show how to write a **custom InputFormat** to process xml data using MR. I don't know how it is related to your problem.

**To summarize , I want to implement wordcount separately on the output records from first mapreduce. Can someone suggest me a good way to do it**

Read the output file generated by first MR and do it.

**or how I can chain a second map reduce job to create the above output or format it better ?**

You can definitely chain jobs together in this fashion by writing multiple driver methods, one for each job. See [this](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html#chaining) for more details and [this](http://gandhigeet.blogspot.in/2012/12/as-discussed-in-previous-post-hadoop.html) for an example.

**I want to do the wordcount for each of text fields separately.**

What do you mean by **separately**?In the traditional wordcount program count of each word is calculated independently of the others.

**Is there any way I can do the wordcount in the same mapper.**

I hope you have understood the wordcount program properly. In the traditional wordcount program you read the input file, one line at a time, slit the line into words and then emit **each word as the key** with **1 as the value**. All this happens inside the Mapper, which is essentially the same Mapper. And then the total count for each word is determined in the Reducer part of your job. If you wish to emit the words with their total counts from the mapper itself you have to read the whole file in the Mapper itself and do the counting. For that you need to set **isSplittable** in your **InputFormat** to **false** so that your input file is read as a whole and goes to just one Mapper.

When you emit something from Mapper and if it is **not a Map only job**, the output of your Mapper automatically goes to the Reducer. Do you need something else?

Comment: Could you please show me your input xml file and explain a bit more what exactly you are trying to do with it?

Comment: My input is a wikipedia dump. Every wikipedia page is an xml file containing entities like title , author , text , revision etc. 
My mapreduce parses title and text and saves them as a key , value pair . Title is the key and Text is the value

Now , I have to do a wordcount on the text present in each page. I have to do the wordcount for each page separately. Suppose you have 3 pages 
Page 1 - Title-1 , text-1
Page 2 - Title-2 , text-2
Page 3 - Title-3 , text-3

I have to the wordcount for Page 1 . The output should be a key , value pair where key is still Title-1 .

Comment: (Cont) - But the value is  composite , it contains each word and the number of times it occurs in the page.

The wordcount of each page has to be done separately . I am unable to figure out how to do it ? 

I am ready to provide as much information I can . But please don't close this page saying "insufficient information provided" as I am not a Computer Science guy and I  never learn programming formally

Comment: Input sample looks like this

    <page>
          <title>ABC</title>
          <id>123</id>
          <revision>
                <id>100</id>
                    ....
          </revision>
          <revision>
                <id>200</id>
            ....
          </revision>
          <revision>
                <id>300</id>
            ....
          </revision>
          <text> This is a sample page about how to implement wordcount in java using hadoop </text>
    </page>

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much for all the details. Let me have a proper look at it. And I don't find any reason to mark this question for closing.

Answer (score 0):

i suggested you can go with regular expression

and perform mapping and grouping.
in hadoop example jar file provide Grep class using this you can perform mapping of your hdfs data using regular expression. and group your maped data.